# Can't add EventListener to object in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I'm having the following code that should add the EventListener for the click to every cell of the table, but if I put the name of function with the parameter, the function seems to start as the interpreter meets the inscruction to add the eventListener. How could I solve this?

```
    function startGame() {
            for(var i = 1; i <= 16; i++) {
                var cellValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16);
                while(isPresent(cellValue)) {
                    cellValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16);
                }
                numbers[cellValue] = true;
                var cell = document.getElementById("cell" + i);
                cell.addEventListener("click", selectCell(cell), false);
                if(cellValue == 0) {
                    cell.innerHTML = "";
                    cell.setAttribute("class", "emptyCell");
                } else {
                    cell.removeAttribute("class");
                    cell.innerHTML = cellValue;
                }   
            }
        }

    function selectCell(cell) {
            if(!isCellSelected) {
                cellSelected = cell;
                isCellSelected = true;
            } else if(cell == cellSelected) {
                cellSelected = null;
                isCellSelected = false;
            } else {
                var cellID = cell.id;
                var effectiveID = parseInt(cellID.substring(4, 6));
                if(isGranted(effectiveID)) {
                    //COMPLETARE METODO                     
                } else {
                    window.alert("Selezionare solo una cella adiacenta alla cella già selezionata.");
                }
            }
        }

        function isGranted(id) {
            var result;
            var existentEffectiveID = parseInt(cellSelected.id.substring(4, 6));
            //Se la cella selezionata è la successiva o precedente in termini orizzontali o verticali allora si puo' selezionare
            if(id == existentEffectiveID - 4 || id == existentEffectiveID + 4 || id == existentEffectiveID + 1 || id == existentEffectiveID - 1) {
                result = true;
            } else {
                result = false;
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: When do you call startGame?  Are you sure it is called after the page loads?

Comment: Yes, it's called after the event "load" of the window object...

Comment: This situation might be a good candidate for [event delegation](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-event-delegation-is-easier-than-you-think/). It might be too advanced for you right now but something to think about for the future.

Comment: Yes event delegation is always best

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the arguments on `cell.addEventListener("click", selectCell(cell), false);` and use `cell.addEventListener("click", selectCell, false);` instead. You can use `this` inside the function to refer to the element cell being clicked.

Comment: Ohhh thank you a lot! I've not been able to find how can I refer to the sender of the call of the function, now it works. Thanks again ;) !

Answer (score 2):

The event listener wants a callback.

```
cell.addEventListener("click", selectCell(cell), false);
```

By giving it `selectCell(cell)` you are effectively saying, "call whatever selectCell() returns" which is undefined.  The other problem is that selectCell() will be called as you are attaching the listener.

Consider the difference below:

```js
var b1 = document.getElementById("b1");
var b2 = document.getElementById("b2");

var myVar = "hello";

function readVar(){
  console.log(myVar);
}
  

// Calling readVar() now will print "hello"
b1.addEventListener("click", readVar(), false);

// You want to wait until the event actually happens
b2.addEventListener("click", readVar, false);

// Now myVar is "world" and that will be printed whenever b2 is clicked
myVar = "world";
```

```html
<button id="b1">Button 1</button>
<button id="b2">Button 2</button>
```